# AWS Code Pipeline for none AWS applications

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-codepipeline

I'm looking at AWS CodePipeline for setting up a CI/CD process with Salesforce DX. I have done similar work on GitLab CI/CD pipeline.

From what I understand and see from playing with it, it seems like it is not a good fit, since all the artifacts, build and deploy is actually running on Salesforce instances; While in AWS CodePipeline you must set up actions, artifact store and more in order to configure the pipeline and those actions and artifact stores does not seems to support integration with Salesforce or SFDX for that matter.

Am I'm missing something or does AWS CodePipline is actually oriented only to applications that can run on AWS varies cloud products?